# SMTP connection issue

Tags: smtp, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I am having an issue connecting to my local ISP's SMTP server.
Is there anybody who can help me with some of the required commands?

I've tried `'HELO'`,`'USER` and  `'PASS'`  commands, but I keep getting a `10053 ECONNABORTED` error. Is anybody willing to help me out with what I'm missing?

And if it is important, my ISP is Roadrunner.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example). You can use telnet to do it manually.